# How can I have changes in gridview updated to datatable that i created in code

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, datasource, gridcontrol

I create a `datatable` in code and set it to a `gridcontrol` (`DevExpress component`) to show it like the code here (add one row to `datatable` and set it as `datasource` of `gridcontrol`):

```
DataTable PersonFamiliesDataTable = new DataTable();

PersonFamiliesDataTable.Columns.Add("BirthDate", typeof(String));
PersonFamiliesDataTable.Columns.Add("Job", typeof(String));
PersonFamiliesDataTable.Columns.Add("NameFamily", typeof(String));

DataRow PersonFamilyRow = PersonFamiliesDataTable.NewRow();

PersonFamilyRow["BirthDate"] = DateTimePicker_FamilyInfo_BirthDate.Text;
PersonFamilyRow["Job"] = FamilyInfo_txt_job.Text;
PersonFamilyRow["NameFamily"] = FamilyInfo_txt_NameFamily.Text;
PersonFamiliesDataTable.Rows.Add(PersonFamilyRow);

grid_Family.DataSource = PersonFamiliesDataTable;
```

The user can change data in my `gridcontrol`. I want to have changes in my `gridcontrol` updated to my `datatable`. How can I do that (row edited, row deleted)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: in `Family_gridView_CellValueChanged` event, add this code:

```
PersonFamiliesDataTable = (DataTable)grid_Family.DataSource;
```

So after any changes happen to cells of grid, my `datatable` is being updated. Be careful, this event comes up when the user change a cell and focus leave it.